# Microsoft SQL Server case sensitive queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possibile to  have databae-wide settings to make sql queries case-sensitive on Microsoft SQL Server, e.g. 2012?

I'm refering to http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm and it turn out for me that I can only modify queries to handle collations per column or to modify schema for specific columns have case-sensitive collations.

If I try

"ALTER DATABASE my_database COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;"

it is not helping. Instead I have a problem with column names in my queries. I'm wonderign if there are separate settings for column name and data case-sensitivity for Ms SQL Server?

Comment: Column name collation is set in stone (or rather, in the system tables) when the database is first created. Altering the database collation after the fact only sets the default collation; it has no effect whatsoever on existing data. Furthermore, the `COLLATE` clauses cannot be used to fix collation issues in object names. If the current collation is not to your liking, you'll have to script and recreate the entire database.